# how do I properly map a list of images returned using getStaticProps ? inside the same component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js

how do i properly map a list of images returned using getStaticProps ?

I had it working when i was using the component i another page and passing a prop to the gallery component. But i want to keep all getstatic props code inside the gallery component.

i keep getting the error
[image]

here is the component code

```js
import galleryStyles from "../styles/Gallery.module.css";
import { Grid, IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import NavigateNextIcon from "@mui/icons-material/NavigateNext";
import NavigateBeforeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/NavigateBefore";

const Gallery = ({ images }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Grid className={galleryStyles.container}>
        <div className={galleryStyles.carousel}>
          <IconButton className={galleryStyles.previous}>
            <NavigateBeforeIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <IconButton className={galleryStyles.next}>
            <NavigateNextIcon />
          </IconButton>

          <ul>
            {images.map((image) => (
              <li>
                <img key={image.id} src={image.url} />
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </Grid>
    </>
  );
};

export default Gallery;

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos?_limit=10"
  );
  const images = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      images,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: @Iams So you don't want `images` passed via props any longer and want the `Gallery` component to make the request for the static props?

Comment: i was importing the gallery component in another component and it worked there. the getStatic props was also in the other component. but i am cleaning up the code, so i want to put the getstaticprops where it is being used, in the gallery component.

Comment: i dont mind using props, but the setup i have now isnt working, i dont know why. I follow the steps on nextjs documentation. maybe i am missing something

Comment: i wanted to use nextjs' feature getstaticprops, but i am trying your solution

Comment: Oh my bad -- didn't see the Next.js tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `getStaticProps` outside of a next page component (`NextPage` in TypeScript). That means you can't use `getStaticProps` in a component which is not inside the `/pages` subfolder.

`getStaticProps` is a Server-Side-Rendering feature which is only executed when the page is loaded (not exactly, but simplified). You can't use this anywhere and anytime in your components.

In your code, `getStaticProps` is not even executed, that is why the `images` array in undefined.

More information in the [Next.js documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#where-can-i-use-getstaticprops)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the array to state using `useEffect` like so

```
const [imagesArray, setImagesArray] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
setImagesArray(prev => [...prev, ...images])
}, [images]);
```

Then loop with `imagesArray.map()`

Comment: the problem remains, its still seeing the images as undefined, i use console log and it is undefined, i think its not getting the data from the server